# Single word which means "to move on"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need one word that means "to move on" as in from a traumatic experience or otherwise emotionally affecting event.

For example:

1. He moved on after the divorce.
2. The soldier was never able to move on after the war.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe *recover*? I could apply to a range of traumatic events.

Comment: Recover is okay but I hope there is something more specific

Comment: Probably the second most common phrase for the concept is *put it behind him*.

Comment: *Outlive* could work, depending on the specific context.

Answer (score 2):

You can [*get over*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/get-over?q=get+over) something traumatic in the sense you were asking about:

> 1 Recover from (an ailment or an upsetting or startling experience):
>   *the trip will help him **get over** Sal’s death*
>
> 2 Overcome (a difficulty).

(Definitions and example sentence from oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Even though *get over* is not strictly a single word, the verbal phrase is "close enough" to single to make it a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think [endure](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Endure) may suggest the idea of facing and overcome hardship with the intent to carry on: (from TFD)

> - to carry on through, despite hardships; undergo: endure an Arctic winter.
> - to continue in existence; last: buildings that have endured for centuries.
> - to support adverse force or influence; suffer without yielding.

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a single word that gives the exact meaning of the phrasal verb *move on* which means to continue with your life after you have dealt with a bad experience but ***thrive*** comes very close in the right context.

> to progress toward or realize a goal despite or because of circumstances —often used with *on*
>
> <sup>http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrive</sup>

Some examples:

- Loss, trauma, and human resilience: have we underestimated the human capacity to thrive after extremely aversive events? 
  <sup>http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14736317</sup>
- Embrace Your Transformation to Thrive After Divorce 
  <sup>http://www.huffingtonpost.com/honoree-corder/how-to-thrive-after-divor_b_3749336.html</sup>
- When Things Go Wrong: You Can Thrive, Not Just Survive 
  <sup>http://tinybuddha.com/blog/when-things-go-wrong-you-can-thrive-not-just-survive/</sup>

---

Also, you often move on when you ***let go***.

Example article:

Learning to Let Go of Past Hurts: 5 Ways to Move On 
<sup>http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2014/07/22/learning-to-let-go-of-past-hurts-5-ways-to-move-on/</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Transcend**, however in the examples provided you would have to specify just what was transcended (risen above):

> - He transcended his bitter feelings after the divorce.
> - The soldier was never able to transcend his experiences in the war.

Answer (score 0):

Persevere(d) would fit the bill I think.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, persevere is more endure as in having gone through. I need something like, emotionally/mentally moving on.

Comment: I'd say you could also try persist in the sense that the individual persisted on, but I'm not a fan of that usage of the word in this case.

Comment: @geebru Your answer would be improved if you [edited](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/202809/edit) it to explain *why* you think *persevered* is appropriate, and include a reference such as a dictionary definition. I encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.